# API results are not consistent

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use [Open Library API](https://openlibrary.org/developers/api) in my small React application. Based on my search query, I make a request to the API and get the results then render it as a list. However, sometimes, the final list is completely different than the original result of the API request. Everything seems good on the network tab; fetch URL is correct and there is no extra request to render a different result.

For example: I type "apple", so I made 5 requests. (final request: https://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=apple on the Network tab). Console log of the fifth request is correct but somehow it renders one (maybe more) time and get another list which is completely irrelevant to the search query. There is still only 5 requests on the Network tab (of course I count only XHR)

There is also other problems that I think are relevant to this API call issue. For example, If I don't limit (getting first X element of the array) the result of an API call, I can see ~400 requests. I am probably doing something fundamentally wrong.

I use Context API to manage pretty much everything.

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-merkle-dnz17

Please note: For your convenience, I added a console.log to see actual API result. You might need to search a couple of times.

I think problem is in Context or Search component.

Context:

```
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext();

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  let URL = `https://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=${query}`;


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setBooks(data.docs.slice(0, 8)))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, [URL]);

  console.log('Click to link to see actual API result: ', URL)

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let value = e.target.value;
    setQuery(value);
  };

  const handleFilter = (value) => {
    const filteredBooks = [...books];
    if (books.length > 0) {
      switch (value) {
        case "alphabetical":
          filteredBooks.sort((a, b) => a.title - b.title);
          setBooks(filteredBooks);
          break;
        case "publishdate":
          filteredBooks.sort(
            (a, b) => b.first_publish_year - a.first_publish_year
          );
          setBooks(filteredBooks);
          break;
        default:
          console.log("reached");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ books, query, handleSearch, handleFilter }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContextProvider, Context };
```

Search:

```
import Filter from "./Filter";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../context/Context";

function Search() {
  const { query, handleSearch } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-container">
        <div className="search-input-wrapper">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by title or author"
            value={query}
            onChange={handleSearch}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Filter />
    </>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Please include a relevant [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *in your question* so we're not guessing what to look at in your sandbox.

Comment: I don't know what parts of my code I should add here. That's why I made a sandbox. Anyway. Please let me know if you want to see more components/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can see you are dispatching a GET request for every state update to `query` and they resolve in an indeterminant order. It seems the shorter queries actually take much longer to resolve than longer queries, i.e. `"title=a"` seems to take significantly longer than `"title=apple"`.

## Solution

It looks like you were on the right track with trying to debounce *something*. You should debounce your GET requests. Use `useMemo` hook to memoize the debounced function.

```
const debouncedFetch = useMemo(
  () =>
    debounce((url) => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setBooks(data.docs.slice(0, 8)))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }, 500),
  []
);

useEffect(() => {
  const URL = `https://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=${query}`;

  query && debouncedFetch(URL);
}, [query]);
```

[image: Edit api-results-are-not-consistent]

Comment: For general usage, I should debounce GET requests or typing (in an input like searching)? I mean if there is a general answer for that.

Comment: @TToprak1 You don't want to debounce your React state/UI updating so I suggest debouncing the high-latency network requests (or other computationally heavy callbacks) instead. Uncontrolled inputs' `onChange` callbacks could be debounced/throttled though.